# Selection row on tableView iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, selection

I have a problem while selecting a row in a tableView, the problem is that when I select a row for a first time it get highlighted with gray but nothing happens, and I have to select again a row to execute the "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" and takes me to an other ViewController

```
// Number of rows in the tableView
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section     {
return 6;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 175.0;
}

// Populating each cell at a time.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    ClientCustomCell *cell = (ClientCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ClientCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = self.clientCustomCell;
        self.clientCustomCell = nil;

        cell.name = [nameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.number = [numberArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.postal = [postalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.locality = [localityArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    [cell setSelectionStyle:(UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue)];
    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"row selecter %d", (int)indexPath.row);
    InfoViewController *info = [[InfoViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:info animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: replace -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath with             - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i found the issues 
you kept `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` method in the place of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Answer (score 5):

You have accidentally implemented **DESELECT**rowAtIndexPAth, not **SELECT**rowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 1):

Update your code with the following code :

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"row selecter %d", (int)indexPath.row);
    InfoViewController *info = [[InfoViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:info animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have implemented `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`, this should be `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Selection row on tableView iOS**

**For Objective c**

```
   -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
    didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

**For Swift 4-5**

```
 import UIKit

 extension UITableView {

func deselectSelectedRow(animated: Bool)
{
    if let indexPathForSelectedRow = self.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        self.deselectRow(at: indexPathForSelectedRow, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

}